# Is there an easy way to strike through text in an app widget?

Tags: android, widget, textview, strikethrough

I was wondering if there is an easy way to strike text within an app widget in Android. In a normal activity, it is pretty easy, using textview flags:

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

But since in an app widget, I can use only remoteviews... I do not know if this is possible

Anyone know something about this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want `xml-only` solution like me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49062515/3579786

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use this:

```
remoteviews.setInt(R.id.YourTextView, "setPaintFlags", Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

Of course you can also add other flags from the android.graphics.Paint class.

Comment: Don't know how this hasn't get more votes, it perfectly answers the question. Thanks.

Comment: First it is unclear what is remoteviews , plus doesn't work for all android versions.

Comment: This is the answer we are looking for, working with app-widgets on androidTextViews are only accessible through removeViews. Accessing TextView directly is not possible at this point.

Answer (score 216):

To do it programatically in a textview, untested in other views >>

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
tv.setText("This is strike-thru");
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: This is not possible for App-Widgets. They only work with RemoteViews and there is no method to read the paint flags.

Answer (score 88):

Another way to do it programmatically which looks a bit less like a hack than the Paint way:

Instead of doing:

```
tv.setText(s);
```

do:

```
private static final StrikethroughSpan STRIKE_THROUGH_SPAN = new StrikethroughSpan();
...
tv.setText(s, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable spannable = (Spannable) tv.getText();
spannable.setSpan(STRIKE_THROUGH_SPAN, 0, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm
Specially when you need some part of TextView to have strikethrough line

Comment: +1 Solution with Spannable worked, thank you so much. You saved my day. Thanks man ;)

Comment: This does not answer the question as this does not apply to `RemoteView`

Comment: @Alex.F I am a bit surprised since this does work for instance in Notifications (which are remote views).  I must admit I haven't tested with AppWidgets though.

Comment: It does work with App Widgets (any framework span that implements ParcelableSpan should work)

Comment: this worked with recyclerView's adapter, unlike the other answer(@ruhalde) which didn't work for it so up vote this.

Answer (score 61):

***2015 Update:*** Folks, this is for very old versions of Android. See other answers for modern solutions!

---

To strike through the entire text view, you can use a specific background image to simulate the strikethrough effect:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_strikethrough"
```

Where the `bg_strikethrough` drawable is a 9-patch that keeps a solid line through the middle, growing either side, with however much padding you think is reasonable. I've used one like this:

> [image]

(enlarged for clarity.. 1300% !)

> [image]

That is my HDPI version, so save it (the first one https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt6BK.png)  as `res/drawable-hdpi/bg_strikethrough.9.png` and the configuration will work as so:

> [image]

Comment: and what to do if the TextView is longer than the text and only the text should be struck through?

Comment: only for black and one line text ... @ruhalde worked for me.

Answer (score 40):

For doing this you can use this

```
 title.setPaintFlags(title.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

and for remove you can use this

```
 title.setPaintFlags(title.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```

Comment: how can i add strike color

Comment: @Harsha this seems to only allow you to use the color of the text. If you want a different strikethrough color you'll have to try other implementation method.

Answer (score 26):

Here is an extension for all you Kotlin folks

```
fun TextView.showStrikeThrough(show: Boolean) {
    paintFlags =
            if (show) paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            else paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
}
```

---

**Usage**

```
textView.showStrikeThrough(true)
```

---

**Limitation**

Strikethroughs can only be the same color as the text

*(i.e. Red text and blue strikethrough is not possible)*

Answer (score 12):

Make a drawable file,
**striking_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

layout xml

```
 <TextView
            ....
            ....
            android:background="@drawable/striking_text"
            android:foreground="@drawable/striking_text"
            android:text="69$"
           />
```

If your min SDK below API level 23 just use the background
**or** just put the background and foreground in the Textview then the android studio will show an error that says create a layout file for API >23 after that remove the  *android:foreground="@drawable/stricking_text"* from the main layout

Output look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 11):

It is really easy if you are using strings:

```
<string name="line"> Not crossed <strike> crossed </strike> </string>
```

And then just:

```
<TextView 
        ...
         android:text="@string/line"
 />
```

Comment: @war_Hero Worked for me, doesn't render in Android Studio's renderer though. Had to actually build it to see it.

Answer (score 9):

For multiline TextView you should use android.text.style.CharacterStyle like this:

```
SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(text);
spannable.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.itemText, spannable);
```

Answer (score 8):

Add the line below:-

```
TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

use your reference instead of "tv"

Comment: This does not reference the question, he's asking about a RemoteViews object in an AppWidget.

Answer (score 6):

try this code

```
textview.setText((Html.fromHtml("<strike>hello world!</strike>")));
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin way

```
val tv = findViewById<View>(R.id.mytext) as TextView
tv.text = "This is strike-through"
tv.paintFlags = tv.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
```

Answer (score 2):

For Lollipop and above. create a drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/onePlusRed" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and use it as foreground.
`android:foreground="@drawable/strike_through"`

Comment: this will only work for single line texts as it's View dependent

Answer (score 2):

Android resources have pretty good [HTML markup support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML)
The below HTML elements are supported:

```
Bold: <b>, <em>
Italic: <i>, <cite>, <dfn>
25% larger text: <big>
20% smaller text: <small>
Setting font properties: <font face=”font_family“ color=”hex_color”>. Examples of possible font families include monospace, serif, and sans_serif.
Setting a monospace font family: <tt>
Strikethrough: <s>, <strike>, <del>
Underline: <u>
Superscript: <sup>
Subscript: <sub>
Bullet points: <ul>, <li>
Line breaks: <br>
Division: <div>
CSS style: <span style=”color|background_color|text-decoration”>
Paragraphs: <p dir=”rtl | ltr” style=”…”>
```

Note however that it's not rendered in android studio layouts preview. Last tested on Android Studio 3.3.1

For example, the Strikethrough will look like that:

```
<string name="cost"><strike>$10</strike> $5 a month</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use data binding!
In XML layout just do app:strike="@{true}"

```html
@BindingAdapter("strike")
fun bindTextView(view: TextView, strike: Boolean) {
    if (strike) {
        view.paintFlags = view.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG or Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
    } else {
        view.paintFlags = 0 or Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin way

`averagePrice.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG`

Comment: You should not set flag but add it to existing, because there can be other flags set (for antialiasing, for example)

Answer (score 0):

you add in :

```
TextView variableTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourText);
```

you set/add in You variable :

```
variableTv.setText("It's Text use Style Strike");
```

and then add .setPaintFlags in variableTv :

```
variableTv.setPaintFlags(variableTv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried few options but, this works best for me:

```
String text = "<strike><font color=\'#757575\'>Some text</font></strike>";
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Another solution as a Kotlin extension:

```
var TextView.isStrikeThrough: Boolean
    get() = (paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) == Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
    set(value) {
        paintFlags = if (value) {
            paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        } else {
            paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've done this on a regular (local) `TextView`, and it should work on the remote variety since the docs list the method as equivalent between the two:

`remote_text_view.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is <del>crossed off</del>."));`

Comment: It does not work :(. I am doing this: 
remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, Html.fromHtml("<del>" + value + "</del>"));

Comment: It might be that `<del>` isn't supported by `Html.fromHtml()`.  Have you tried `<strike>` or `<s>`?

Comment: Thanks Blrfl, but it does not work either. It seems that only a few HTML tags are suported by Html.fromHtml().

Comment: Bummer.  Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: how can i achieve for price with strike like shopping apps for offers

Answer (score -1):

I know, I am answering an old question, it might be helpful for someone else, for striking out a particular portion of TextView programmatically.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("Text need to be set here", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable spannable = (Spannable) textView.getText();
spannable.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 5, 8, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

So, in this example code, 5 is starting position and 8 is ending position of text need to be stricken out, so after running this code we can get the text "need" with striked out. Hope it will helpful for someone else.