# How to cross/scratch some text in Android?

Tags: android, text

How can I set a style in Android, which cross/scratch the Text in a TextView? Is it possible?

Comment: check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

Scratch:

```
 textView.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Remove scratch:

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```