# creating a strikethrough text?

Tags: android, user-interface

Can I create a strikethrough text in Android, I mean adding a special value in the `TextView` tag that can make this possible?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans" 
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget

Comment: check here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186622/835883

Answer (score 355):

You can use the following code [copied from another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget/6739637#6739637):

```
TextView someTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_text_view);
someTextView.setText(someString);
someTextView.setPaintFlags(someTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

See also [Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG):

> For painting text, there are several bit flags for doing things like
> bold, italics, and yes strikethrough. So to enable the strikethrough,
> you need to flip the bit that corresponds to this flag. The easiest
> way to do this is to use a bitwise-or on the current flags and a
> constant that corresponds to a set of flags with only the
> strikethrough flag enabled.

Edit from [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786544/creating-a-strikethrough-text#comment25615063_9786629) by [Ε Г И І И О](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687190/) :

For any one wanting to remove this flag, this is how:

```
someTextView.setPaintFlags(someTextView.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```

Comment: it really works, but can i change its properities i mean its size, its color something like that

Comment: nawfal cuteberg, sure you can ;)

Comment: For any one wanting to remove this flag, this is how: `someTextView.setPaintFlags(someTextView.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));`

Comment: @ΕГИІИО what does the ~ symbol mean?

Comment: @BobbyJackson, that is the unary bitwise complement operator.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО it reverts all the bits. so let's say strike_thru is 00100, then ~ does 11011. If you then & it with the existing flags, it will keep all the original flags but unset the strike_thru bit

Comment: how to strike thru a specific word? Ex: "I will be back". Here I want to just strike thru only "back". Is it possible?

Comment: @ΕГИІИО Resetting works only the first time. After that nothing happens

Comment: I tried unstrike back using. TextView.setPaintFlags(0);works fine.

Comment: As Kotlin extension function: 

    fun TextView.strikeThrough(enable: Boolean) {
 paintFlags = if (enable) {
  (paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)
 } else {
  paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
 }
}

Answer (score 46):

If you are using Kotlin:

```
your_text_view.apply {
    paintFlags = paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
    text = "Striked thru text"
}
```

Comment: And to undo it: `paintFlags = paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()`

Answer (score 42):

It is really easy if you are using strings:

```
<string name="line"> Not crossed <strike> crossed </strike> </string>
```

And then just:

```
<TextView 
        ...
         android:text="@string/line"
 />
```

Comment: this didn't show as a strikethrough in the ui editor, but it does strike the text on the device

Comment: This may (and likely will) fail in API 21+

Comment: This answer has 3 years. I am not sure if it is necessary to edit answers explaining until what API or version are useful. If there is any rule in stackoverflow which at least recommed it, I will do it without problems.

Comment: This worked in every API level that I've tested on (tested on 15, 25, and 27)

Comment: Some devices don't honor things like this or the underline

Answer (score 41):

You can do this in three ways, by either setting foreground in `TextView` or setting `PaintFlag` or declaring a string as `<strike>your_string</strike>` in `strings.xml`. For example,

**Through PaintFlag**

This is the simplest method you just have to set strikethrough flag on your TextView as,

```
yourTextView.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

it will strike through your TextView.

**Through foreground drawable(Works only for API 23+)**

If your minSdkVersion is API version 23 +, then you can strike through your TextView by setting a foreground as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Now, you just have to set above drawable in your TextView as `foreground`. For example,

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Textview with StrikeThrough"
    android:foreground="@drawable/strikethrough_foreground" />  <!-- this is available above --!>
```

**Through strings.xml**

In this method, you have to declare your string in `strings.xml` as strike through as,

```
<string name="strike_line"> <strike>This line is strike throughed</strike></string>
```

**Note**

But I recommend you to strike through your TextView by setting foreground drawable. Because through drawable you can easily set your strike-through line color(as like I set as red color in above example) or size or any other style property. While in the other two methods default text color is strikethrough color.

Answer (score 21):

try this :

```
richTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rich_text);  

    // this is the text we'll be operating on  
    SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");  

    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);  

    // make "ipsum" (characters 6 to 11) one and a half time bigger than the textbox  
    text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 6, 11, 0);  

    // make "dolor" (characters 12 to 17) display a toast message when touched  
    final Context context = this;  
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View view) {  
            Toast.makeText(context, "dolor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        }  
    };  
    text.setSpan(clickableSpan, 12, 17, 0);  

    // make "sit" (characters 18 to 21) struck through  
    text.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 18, 21, 0);  

    // make "amet" (characters 22 to 26) twice as big, green and a link to this site.  
    // it's important to set the color after the URLSpan or the standard  
    // link color will override it.  
    text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 22, 26, 0);  
    text.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.djsad.com"), 22, 26, 0);  
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 22, 26, 0);  

    // make our ClickableSpans and URLSpans work  
    richTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());  

    // shove our styled text into the TextView          
    richTextView.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 16):

In **Kotlin** you can create extension property:

```
inline var TextView.strike: Boolean
    set(visible) {
        paintFlags = if (visible) paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        else paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
    }
    get() = paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG == Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
```

And use:

```
textView.strike = true
```

Answer (score 15):

I am just copying my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget/27313243#27313243). Hope it will help for someone
If you have a single word we can use drawable.
Following is the example:

```
<item android:state_pressed="false"><shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

if you have multiple lines you can use the following code:

```
TextView someTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_text_view);
someTextView.setText(someString);
someTextView.setPaintFlags(someTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)
```

Answer (score 11):

This fits nicely into databinding:

```
@BindingAdapter("strikethrough")
@JvmStatic
fun strikethrough(view: TextView, show: Boolean) {
    view.paintFlags = if (show) {
        view.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
    } else {
        view.paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
    }
}
```

Then in your xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line_item_name"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Club sandwich with ranch dressing"
        app:strikethrough="@{viewModel.isItemChecked}"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use this and you are done .
For Activity :

```
TextView t= (TextView).findViewById(R.id.thousand));
t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

For Xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_original_cash_amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:text="Rs. 1,999"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/text_view_original_cash_amount"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/text_view_original_cash_amount"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/text_view_original_cash_amount"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/text_view_original_cash_amount" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ingenious solution

Comment: But this `XML` solution isn't too much complex, I mean for every textview you have to add an extra relative layout and a view.

Comment: For now , i have only this solution , if i get another solution . I must share with you .

Answer (score 5):

**In kotlin:**

to do:

```
textView.paintFlags= textView.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
```

to undo:

```
textView.paintFlags= textView.paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
```

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by `alejandro-h-cruz`, this is the Kotlin extension function to help doing so.

```kotlin
    private fun TextView.strikeThrough(shouldStrike: Boolean) {
        paintFlags = if (shouldStrike) {
            paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        } else {
            paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried few options above but, this works best for me:

```
String text = "<strike><font color=\'#757575\'>Some text</font></strike>";
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

cheers

Comment: The HTML presentational inline element for strikethrough is <strike> or <s> This element was, however, deprecated in the 1999 HTML 4.01 standard, and replaced by the <del> tag, a semantic element representing deleted text, which user agents (typically web browsers) often render as a strikethrough.[3][4] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough

Though not <del> not <strike> works for me

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to change the STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG bit.

It's by getting the [`Paint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint) object associated to the [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) and using the [`setStrikeThruText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#setStrikeThruText(boolean)) function like this:

```
textView.getPaint().setStrikeThruText(/* boolean expression */);
```

Documentation says about it:

> Helper for setFlags(), setting or clearing the STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG bit

There are functions for setting, clearing or reading other bits too.

Answer (score 0):

In your observable view model

```
fun getStrikeContent(): String {
    return "Hello"
}


 companion object {
    @BindingAdapter("strike")
    @JvmStatic
    fun loadOldPrice(view: TextView, value: String) {
        view.text = value
        view.paintFlags = STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
    }
}
```

then in your xml

```
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:strike="@{itemViewModel.strikeContent}" />
```