# Android : Strike out Text with bold or thicker line than default STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using following for strike text.

```
 viewHolder.price_red.setPaintFlags(viewHolder.price_red
                    .getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Its working but I want to increase size of strike through line.

Can anybody help me how to increase size of line ??

Comment: By size do you mean thickness?

Comment: @CarlSaldanha yes thickness of line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the thickness of the strikethrough line.

As you can see from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) its just a flag. Either on or off.

There are a couple of options though (more hacks than solutions):

1. Make the text bold or stroke it. This will automatically stroke the strikethrough too which will make it more visible
2. Manually draw the line with `drawLine`. (This would be really difficult to do accurately though)

Comment: Thanks @carl its helpful answer.. +1 for give solutions also.

Answer (score 2):

This can not be achieved directly as Android doesn't provide any API for the same.

Now, you will have to go Custom way to draw the thicker line.. 1) DrawLine 2)Use Line Image over EditText

I have tried using a `EditText` and a `ImageView` under a `RelativeLayout` and it worked quite nicely for me.

XML Code :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etStrike"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Strike Thru Text Here"
            android:textColor="@color/blacktext"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivStrike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/blacktext" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA Code :

```
    EditText etStrike = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etStrike);
    ImageView ivStrike = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivStrike);

    float textSize = etStrike.getTextSize()/2;
    int textLength = etStrike.getText().length();
    int totalLengthApprox = (int) (textLength * textSize)-textLength;
    int height = 6; // YOUR_REQUIRED_HEIGHT

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(totalLengthApprox,height);
    param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL|RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    param.setMargins((int)textSize, 0, 0, 0);
    ivStrike.setLayoutParams(param);
```

I have tested only a few `TextSize` and `Device Resolutions` and most important this can work only for **singleline EditText** for multiline the logic becomes more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to go about it:  use a layer-list and place as your  textview background.  Here i am assuming your textviews background is white (#FFFFFF)

create in the drawables folder a file called
strikethru.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/> 
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#8d8d8d"/> <!-- adjust color you want here -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

then in your textview do this:

```
    <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_prod_price"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                                android:text="1,290 B"      

android:background="@drawable/strikethru_line"
                                android:textColor="#070707"
                                android:textSize="13sp" />
```

the padding right of 3dp makes the strike through more evident.