# Android: How to add strikethrough to TextView by clicking on checkBox in ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I am making GroceryList app. In my i want to implement Strikethrough to the TextView when clicking on the checkbox of ListView item.

When i click on checkbox the item should be check as a Strikethrough.

Please provide some sample code to implement Strikethrough in Listview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `HTML.fromHTML` to assign HTML code to a TextView. If I remember well, there's the tag `<strike>` in HTML.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9786629/