# Strike through text setting in action bar tab dynamicaly

Tags: android

I want to set text in action bar tab dynamically. Showing that the feature is not available.  How to do that? i had changed the disable tab icon dynamically as you can see in the image in the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_8n82ljiOxIcUZOeHJsdVRZUzQ/view?usp=sharing)

```
audioTab = actionBar.newTab();
actionBar.setIcon(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getIcon(i));
actionBar.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
actionBar.setTabListener(this);
actionBar.addTab(audioTab);
//changing icon dynamically
audioTab.setIcon(R.drawable.audio_disabled);
videoTab.setIcon(R.drawable.video_disabled);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code, how are you setting/accessing your tabs?

Comment: yes pls check @Marko

Answer (score 1):

I did a little research, and because you are not using TabHost (which can access [each seperate view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577688/android-change-tab-text-color-programmatically?lq=1)), you should set each Tab a custom view, via **setCustomView()**, and when you want to change it

- get the tab via `actionBar.getTabAt()`
- tab has methods like **getCustomView()** where you can find your custom text view (via **findViewById**) and than just apply strike through text like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786544/creating-a-strikethrough-text-in-android) demonstrates

`TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_text_view);
 textView.setText(someString);
 textView.setPaintFlags(textView .getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);`

Or you can apply a different custom view, instead of changing the existing text view.

Let me know if you need any further help or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A few answers for changing the title/icon of the `ActionBar` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483393/how-do-i-change-the-android-actionbar-title-and-icon).

As for 'strikethrough' text, you would likely need to override the `ActionBar` class so that it intercepts text changes, and draws a line through the text based on it's width... not that I can think of a single reason why you would want to have a strkethrough effect on what is essentially a page title. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) is some starting points on styling the `ActionBar`.

Here's a link I found by searching for `"extend ActionBar" android` in Google. [This guy seems to be having a go of it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java).

There should be plenty of pointers if you're sharp enough to decipher the source code.

Comment: did you check the image that i attached in question.I just want to show the user that this feature is not available in actionbar tab not actionbar