# Create image type TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I am new to Android. I Want to create an TextView like My Image.I search a lot, but I don't get Any Idea. 
In My TextView how to draw a line on Text. Please help me.

[image]

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9786629

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For set Strikethrough.

```
textView.setPaintFlags(txtView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
textView.setText("10.00 AM");
```

For clear Strikethrough

```
textView.setPaintFlags(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can directly create this line in layout file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/viewline">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello to all"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
<View
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#000000"></View>

</RelativeLayout>
```

which gives a view like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this ：

```
tv.getPaint().setFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```