# can I define middle-lined text in an Android layout xml file

Tags: android, text

How can I define middle-lined(strikethrough) text in an Android layout xml file?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To strike through, you can use a background image to create the strikethrough effect:

```
 android:background="@drawable/strike_through"
```

Where strike_through drawable is a 9-patch image that keeps a line through the middle. This is the easiest way to implement it.

or you can do it programatically as this.

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
t.setText("Text here");
t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: Can I change the color of this middle line ?

Comment: for the xml implementation you just need to change the image that you use for background. for the programmatic method i am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: how do you do this in kotlin?

Comment: where to find `strike_through` image

Answer (score 24):

[6 Amazing Ways - Android TextView Strikethrough XML & Kotlin/Java examples](https://androidride.com/android-textview-strikethrough-xml/)

[image: Android TextView Strikethrough XML]

[Screenshot - Android TextView Strikethrough XML & Kotlin/java Example -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t6ij.png)

1. Using strike element.

   **strings.xml**

`<string name="strike_text">1. <strike>StrikeThrough</strike> Using strike</string>`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/strike_text"
/>
```

2. **Using STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG**

   *Kotlin*

   ```
   textview2.paintFlags = textview2.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
   textview2.text = "2. StrikeThrough Using Paint Flags
   ```

   *Java*

   `textview2.setPaintFlags(textview2.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
       textview2.setText("2. StrikeThrough Using Paint Flags");`
3. **Using SpannableString**

*Kotlin*

`val content1 = "3.1 StrikeThrough Using SpannableString"
        val spannableString1 = SpannableString(content1)
        spannableString1.setSpan(StrikethroughSpan(),0,content1.length,0)
        textview31.text = spannableString1`

*Java*

```
textview2.setPaintFlags(textview2.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    textview2.setText("2. StrikeThrough Using Paint Flags");    `
```

Answer (score 17):

If you define a BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter("strikeThrough")
public static void strikeThrough(TextView textView, Boolean strikeThrough) {
    if (strikeThrough) {
        textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    } else {
        textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

it's just

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    app:strikeThrough="@{true}"
    .../>
```

in XML layout file.

Comment: I wanted to use data binding and to set text to strikethrough based on ViewModel logic. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

To do it in only xml file, this is what I do:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_original_cash_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="$36000"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/text_view_original_cash_amount"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/text_view_original_cash_amount"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

In kotlin it can be done as:

```
your_textView.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
```

Answer (score 2):

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

you can use the above code in activity to have strike over the text.

And to set through xml refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget)

Answer (score 0):

Not xml, but programmatically in Kotlin
Please refer to the code below for how to set and remove it.

```
fun setStrikeThrough(textView: TextView) {
    textView.paintFlags = textView.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
}

fun removeStrikeThrough(textView: TextView) {
    textView.paintFlags = textView.paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
}
```