# How to strike through obliquely on TextView

Tags: android

Is there any simple way how to draw obliquely strike through on TextView? Now I'm using this code:

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

But I need something like this:
[image]
I'm not very familiar with Paint API how to simply achive this so any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Hello read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget

Comment: I saw that post, but I need it obliquely. I tried using 9patch before, but the outcome looks ugly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's pretty easy with a custom `TextView` class. Check out the [Canvas guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) from the documentation for more info on this. Note the comments where you can change the color/width:

```
public class ObliqueStrikeTextView extends TextView
{
    private int dividerColor;
    private Paint paint;

    public ObliqueStrikeTextView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ObliqueStrikeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ObliqueStrikeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context)
    {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        //replace with your color
        dividerColor = resources.getColor(R.color.black);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(dividerColor);
        //replace with your desired width
        paint.setStrokeWidth(resources.getDimension(R.dimen.vertical_divider_width));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(0, getHeight(), getWidth(), 0, paint);
    }
}
```

You can use it in a layout file by fully qualifying the view with your package, like this:

```
<your.package.name.ObliqueStrikeTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1234567890"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Here's the end result:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I just add some "anti-analising" to make it look better. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this answer for non-static strike through width. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890541/3541465