# draw line through text in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have started to make an application similar to concept of "To do task manager", in which i need to make a textview cancelable, like, when user clicks on done image, whole text in the view will be cancelled.

Can anyone please guide me on, how to achieve this mechanism ??

Comment: I think this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4752292/617044

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to strike through text in an app widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This can help you.

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    tv.setText("This is strike-thru");
    tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

You can use it in your code,however necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin

```
tv.text = "This is text"
tv.paintFlags = tv.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
```

Comment: Thanks nice decision
`tv.apply {
   text = "This is text"
   paintFlags = paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to strikethrough only part of the TextView text you can use [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder). Note that it is `tv.text = ssb` not `tv.text = ssb.toString()`

```
val text = "tv.text = ssb.toString()"
val ssb = SpannableStringBuilder(text)
ssb.setSpan(
    StrikethroughSpan(),
    13, // start of the span (inclusive)
    24, // end of the span (exclusive)
    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
)
tv.text = ssb
```

When you run it, it comes out like this:

```
tv.text = ssb.toString()
```