# How to Create Line Drawable On Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

How to Create Drawable on Android look Like text below:

> <del>Remove</del>

Comment: You can draw horizontal line on drawable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [draw line through text in textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970267/draw-line-through-text-in-textview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to strike through text in an app widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make text-view exactly like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348185/how-to-make-text-view-exactly-like-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for single word we can use drawable.
Following is the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false"><shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

for multiple line use below:-

```
TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

use your reference instead of "tv"

Comment: @Ahmad glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Programatically:

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    tv.setText("Remove");
    tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

From xml file:

```
    <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           >
     <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Remove"
           />
     <View
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="1dp"
           android:background="@color/black"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```