# Strike the string in android

Tags: java, android

**My requirement:**

I want strike the particular strings in my textview.

Please take a look at the image below. In **project 2 box** task 8,task 5,task 1,task 3 are striked.

[image]

**What I am tried:**

After refer this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget),

I can strike whole text view. (but I can`t strike particular string wise)

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
 tv.setText("This is strike-thru");
 tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

**My problem:**

1.I want to strike the particular strings only.

2.Not entire textbox.

Comment: You can keep more than one TextViews for that..one for keeping the strikethrough text and the other for the normal text..

Comment: Are the texts generated dynamically?

Comment: @Lal good idea..But I get these strings from webservice..so I can`t  do this.

Comment: You could use a [`StrikethroughSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StrikethroughSpan.html)

Comment: Ok @ranjith..Check my anwer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [this link](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.com/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html) , you can see all of text styling there.
you need to use spannableString . just choose style and specify the start and end index of your string to get style.

```
    SpannableString string = new SpannableString("your text here");

    string.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, string.length(), 0); 

    textView.setText(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to add a Striked-Through text **programmatically**

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is <del>strike-thru</del>."));
```

**OR**

if you want to add it through your xml file you can do it as follows

```
<string name="line"> This is <strike> strike-thru</strike> </string>
```

And in your Textview just add:

```
<TextView 
        ...
         android:text="@string/line"
 />
```

**UPDATE**

If `<del>` is not working, try using `<strike>` like,

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is <strike>strike-thru</strike>."));
```

Comment: Can I create this string at runtime?

Comment: Yes of course..you can use it just like you use the normal `setText()`.

Comment: not working..I try Html.fromHtml().. but string not striked..I can`t use 2nd solution..Because I get the strings runtime.

Comment: <del>,<strike> are not working on android textview am also looking for solution please help me.am having one textview with current price and stricked price please help me

Comment: The tags <del></del><strike></strike> does not work for Androids pre-lollipop