# Strike through Multiline TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This in not a duplicate question, i found some question but they were not having satisfied answers, answers were not available for multiline textviews.

I have already checked this below link but they were not enough useful:
[Is there an easy way to strike through text in an app widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget)

I want to create a line across the center of a `TextView` (striked `TextView`), but I want to do it in XML layout, not in the Java code.

I have already achieved this result through the use of JAVA code as such:

```
myTextView.setPaintFlags(myTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

I would like the same result, but in the below XML code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    />
```

[image]

Thanks again.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate. The answer is the same, but te question there is about a widget, which has different limitations.

Comment: @yedidyak, thanks you got it

Answer (score 3):

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="XYZ"
        android:background="@drawable/line"/>
```

**line.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white"/>

</shape>
```

Try this !

**EDIT**

The above code will work only for single line text.
For Multi line text use below code :

```
<string name="strike_text">
        <strike>sample TextView \nSecond line of TextView</strike>
</string>
```

And use it as

```
android:text="@string/strike_text"
```

Comment: exact code, but not able to do work for text with new line(multiline)

Comment: @Androider see my Edits

Comment: but string is dynamic.

Comment: then setPaintFlags is the only solution, according to me

Comment: and your set string method is also not working

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use an image.

create image with horizontal line and transparent background and set it as background of `TextView`

```
android:background="@drawable/strike_through"
```

**Or**

Create an xml file which will draw a line and set it as background of your `TextView`

```
<shape android:shape="line">
     <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Comment: i think your xml code is not completed, and for image we should need 9-patch image,

Comment: would it work on multiline textview, using image

Comment: ok. i'm going to update image

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this in xml is to create a drawable of the strike and set it as the background of the `TextView`. An example of the drawable would be:

```
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="line">
         <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```