# how to make text-view exactly like this

Tags: android, textview

Trying to build a shopping cart and want to display discounted price and for old price want to show it as in image

[image]

Comment: See this post I looked up with "android strikethrough" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget

Answer (score 1):

```
textview.getPaint().setFlags(Paint. STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG|Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);  

textView.getPaint().setFlags(0);  //make it gone
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spannable to achieve this, its more flexible in case you need to put this only in a part of the text. Here is an example:

```
textview.setText("29,500", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
final StrikethroughSpan STRIKE_THROUGH_SPAN = new StrikethroughSpan();
Spannable spannable = (Spannable) textview.getText();
spannable.setSpan(STRIKE_THROUGH_SPAN, 0, textview.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textview.setText(spannable);
```