# Use overline in Android

Tags: java, android, html

I am trying to display repeating decimals in a TextView but using the HTML tag  in Html.fromHtml is not working. Are there any other ways to display lines over numbers?

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this:

```
private static final StrikethroughSpan STRIKE_THROUGH_SPAN = new StrikethroughSpan();
...
tv.setText(s, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable spannable = (Spannable) tv.getText();
spannable.setSpan(STRIKE_THROUGH_SPAN, 0, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Source: [Is there an easy way to strike through text in an app widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget)

Comment: This is for striking through though, I need the line over the text. Or can I modify it somewhere?

Comment: can you show me an image of want you want it to look like?

Comment: Like those numbers in the table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Table_of_values