# Using strikethrough in ListView using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, strikethrough

I have added elements in ListView through database using array adapter. Here I want the element to have a strikethrough. How can I do this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
String q4 = "select * from todolist;";
Cursor d = database.rawQuery(q4, null);
if(d != null && d.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String element =d.getString(d.getColumnIndex("elist"));
        al.add(element);
        ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,al);
        list.setAdapter(ad);
    } while (d.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: adapter and set adapter write out side of while loop.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel how will that help?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget) for strike through.

Comment: @KNeerajLal All the answers here are working on a text view. Since I am using a array adapter, I don't have a text View. That's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer, Array Adapter cannot alter the view of its contents. Using Base adapter is the best option.