# how to add stroke on text

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I can't find a way to put a stroke on text (on the text, not on the whole text view box) ,  the stroke should be around the letters.
is there any custom text view or library or drawing can be implemented to draw a stroke

```
        <TextView
            style="@style/Header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:text="HELLO DROID"
            />
```

i expect the text to look like so , (the stroke color is red)
[image]

Comment: Do you mean a strikethrough text? If yes, this question is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget

Comment: @gpunto thank you, but no that's not what I'm looking for, the stroke should be around the letters.

Comment: Do you please add screenshots of your expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried below two ways for adding stroke to text :

First is add shadow to your TextView:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
```

The output of above code is:
[image]

Second I found GitHub project **`android-outline-textview`**.
[Please follow this Link](https://github.com/biomorgoth/android-outline-textview)

For this you need to add `StrokedTextView` and related files to your project
after that add below Code in XML file:

```
 <com.skd.stackdemo.StrokedTextView
        android:id="@+id/stroke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
```

Add below code in Java file:

```
StrokedTextView stroke = findViewById(R.id.stroke);
stroke.setStrokeColor(Color.RED);
stroke.setStrokeWidth(1f);
```

The output of above code is:
[image]

I hope it works for you.

Comment: I would highly recommend _not_ using that library. It calls `setTextColor()` in `onDraw()`, which invalidates the `TextView`, and causes an infinite redraw loop. Just FYI.